# Bootstrap not loading styles properly

Tags: node.js, bootstrap-4, pug

I'm trying to write a small application using bootstrap but it seems it doesn't load the styles at all, even tho i included all bootstrap references properly, here is some code (i am using PUG, but i can provide the final HTML if needed)

```
extends layout

block content
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/index.css')

  .container
    .row
      .col-md-8
        section
          h1.entry-title
            span Sign Up
          hr
          form#signup.form-horizontal(method='post' name='signup' enctype='multipart/form-data')
            .form-group
              label.control-label.col-sm-3
                | Email ID 
                span.text-danger *
              .col-md-8.col-sm-9
                .input-group
                  span.input-group-addon
                    i.fas.fa-envelope-open-text
                  input#emailid.form-control(type='email' name='emailid' placeholder='Enter your Email ID' value='')
            .form-group
              .col-xs-offset-3.col-xs-10
                input.btn.btn-primary(name='Submit' type='submit' value='Sign Up')
```

The code of layout is this

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
  head
    title= title

    meta(charset='utf-8')
    meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no')
    link(href='bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css', rel='stylesheet', media="all")

  body
    block content

    script(src='jquery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js')
    script(src='bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.js')
    script(src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/ae629fb23c.js')
```

I did check all the files and it does load bootstrap css and js, it just doesn't apply any styles, as seen here

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i31ni.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your templates are setup, the `link` element loading your custom styles is placed in the `body` instead of the `head` where it belongs. Try something like this, which makes use of the [prepend and append](https://pugjs.org/language/inheritance.html#block-append-prepend) directives:

**layout.pug**

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
  head
    block head
      title= title
      meta(charset='utf-8')
      meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no')
      link(href='bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css', rel='stylesheet', media="all")

  body
    block content
      script(src='jquery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js')
      script(src='bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.js')
      script(src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/ae629fb23c.js')
```

**page.pug**

```
extends layout

append head
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/index.css')

prepend content
  .container
    .row
      .col-md-8
        section
          h1.entry-title
            span Sign Up
          hr
          form#signup.form-horizontal(method='post' name='signup' enctype='multipart/form-data')
            .form-group
              label.control-label.col-sm-3
                | Email ID 
                span.text-danger *
              .col-md-8.col-sm-9
                .input-group
                  span.input-group-addon
                    i.fas.fa-envelope-open-text
                  input#emailid.form-control(type='email' name='emailid' placeholder='Enter your Email ID' value='')
            .form-group
              .col-xs-offset-3.col-xs-10
                input.btn.btn-primary(name='Submit' type='submit' value='Sign Up')
```

Comment: Actually, it did solve the issue, turns out the code itself was wrong, i guess they changed things between bootstrap 3 and 4 and it broke my input group code.